# Django, ModelFormField: using evaluated queryset several times

Tags: python, django

I have a ModelFormSet with ~5 forms; each copy of form has a `ModelChoiceField` with all fields of one model Distance, ~1000 items.

I want to make just one evaluation of the queryset `Distance.objects.all()`, not 5 such queries, and use its result in each form. How can I do it?

I tried to provide the argument `form_kwargs={'distances': models.Distance.objects.all()}` to a ModelFormSet; but it appears that this queryset is still evaluated for each form copy. Can I ask Django to do it just once?

Here is my form code:

```
class RaceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    distance = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=models.Distance.objects.none(),
        required=True)
    distance_real = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=models.Distance.objects.none(),
        required=False)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        distances = kwargs.pop('distances')
        super(RaceForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['distance'].queryset = distances
        self.fields['distance_real'].queryset = distances
```

And here is how I create a formset:

```
def getRaceFormSet(user, event, data=None):
    RaceFormSet = modelformset_factory(models.Race, form=forms.RaceForm, can_delete=True, extra=N_EXTRA_RACES)
    return RaceFormSet(
        data=data,
        queryset=event.race_set.select_related('distance').order_by(
            'distance__distance_type', '-distance__length', 'precise_name'),
        initial=[{'event': event, 'created_by': user}] * N_EXTRA_RACES,
        form_kwargs={'distances': models.Distance.objects.all().order_by('-popularity_value', 'distance_type', 'length')},
    )
```

Comment: Show us your relevant code!

Comment: Sorry for late response. Here it is!